# Project with UseMaui set to true not recognised as a MAUI project

Tags: maui, visual-studio-2022

This is with VS 2022 for Windows.

I've got a MAUI solution and project which works fine.

One of my colleagues is trying to build application, but the MAUI project is not recognised as such.

The Properties page for the project is showing it as a Console Application, with no MAUI settings.

He's got MAUI installed, and all the appropriate VS Workloads.

In my VS, if I set UseMaui to *false* I get the same as him - but resetting to *true* reverts back to the project showing as a MAUI project.

One other observation - when I change UseMaui and save the project file, VS prompts that the project must be reloaded. On his installation, it's not prompting - so maybe isn't recognising that the project has changed.

He's running VS 2022 17.8.1, I'm running VS 2022 17.7.4

Any thoughts? Is this a VS 2022 bug?

Comment: Is this VS Mac?

Comment: Good point - no, VS Windows. I'll update question.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with an old project that i made in maui 6 , since the last release to maui 8 as lts (last week) , the project wasn't recognized anymore as a maui project becouse i didn't have anymore the "sdk" for 6.
I fixed it upgrading the solution to maui 8 , your colleague might be facing the same issue

this might help you to upgrade your solution
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Upgrading-.NET-MAUI-from-.NET-7-to-.NET-8

Comment: That's a good suggestion - I need to check whether he's got the appropriate SDK installed. I'll check and respond back here.